# In spring mvc, how to I select an enum and pass it as a parameter in a @GetMapping method

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

When I select a vendor in order to create a file, it selects but nothing happens, what am I doing wrong here? There is a service class which accepts a vendor as in th code below.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/createFile")
    public String selectVendor(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Customer());
        model.addAttribute("vendorType", Vendor.values());
        return "vendor";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/createFile/{vendor}")
    public ResponseEntity selectVendor(@PathVariable("vendor") Vendor vendor) {
        String message = "error creating file";
        if (vendorSrvice.createFile(vendor)) {
            message = "file created successfully";
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/createFile}" th:object="${customer}">
    <div>
        <lebel th:for="vendorType">select Vendor</lebel>
        <select th:field="*{vendor}">
            <option th:each="vendorType : ${vendorType}"
                    th:text="${vendorType.name}"
                    th:value="${vendorType}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="..."><input type="submit" value="Create file"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? such as `ConversionFailedException`?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the issue just by using `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`. I also removed the `/` from the `createFile th:` action.